# Why is #map more efficient than #each?

Tags: ruby, performance

When all you've got is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. So it can be said of the `Array#each` method in Ruby, before discovering the utility, elegance, and syntactic pleasure of `Array#map` and `Array#select` and other iterable methods. What I'm curious of is:

**Why is there an actual increase in performance when using a more precise iterable method? Is this true in general?**

For example, in

```rb
require 'benchmark'

array = (1..100000).to_a

puts Benchmark.measure {
  100.times do
    array.map { |el| el.even? }
  end
}

puts Benchmark.measure {
  100.times do
    new_array = []
    array.each do |el| 
      new_array << el.even? 
    end
  end
}

# ruby bench.rb
# 0.450598   0.015524   0.466122 (  0.466802)
# 0.496796   0.018525   0.515321 (  0.516196)
```

`Benchmark` always shows a temporal performance difference in favor of `Array#map`. In the following code:

```rb
puts Benchmark.measure {
  100.times do
    array.select { |el| el.even? }
  end
}

puts Benchmark.measure {
  100.times do
    new_array = []
    array.each do |el| 
      if el.even? 
         new_array << el
      end
    end
  end
}

# ruby bench.rb
# 0.405254   0.007965   0.413219 (  0.413733)
# 0.471416   0.008875   0.480291 (  0.481079)
```

`Array#select` beats a jerry-rigged `Array#each` every time.

So why do these more precise methods produce notably better performance? And is this a general axiom in Ruby and/or all languages?

Comment: FWIW, in your second example in both cases, `new_array` will be 100 times larger than the arrays returned by map and select by the time your benchmark finishes running, since it doesn't get reset between runs. No idea if that accounts for the performance difference or not, but you might want to check.

Comment: I think we can conclude that purpose-built methods are always faster (or at least no slower) than more general methods used in a particular way, for the simple reason that one option for the writer of the former is to put a wrapper on the latter, and Ruby's core method writers work hard to optimise performance. I suppose one could argue that some core methods may not be optimized for speed because of memory considerations, but they still would be optimized for some performance metric and therefore would be no worse, by the same metric, than adapted general methods.

Comment: Shouldn't `new_array = []` be inside the `100.times` block to get the same result? You are currently comparing 2 different tasks.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks for the heads up. Fixed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both of your examples, the second piece of code allocates 100 times as much memory as the first piece of code. It also performs approximately log_1.5(100) resizes of the array (assuming a standard textbook implementation of a dynamic array with a growth factor of 1.5). Resizing an array is expensive (allocating a new chunk of memory, then an O(n) copy of all elements into the new chunk of memory). More generally, garbage collectors *hate* mutation, they are much more efficient at collecting lots of small short-lived objects than keeping alive a few large long-lived objects.

In other words, in the first example, you are measuring `Array#map` and `Array#select`, respectively, whereas in the second example, you are not only measuring `Array#each`, but also `Array#<<` as well as array resizing and memory allocation. It is impossible to tell from the benchmarking results, which of those contributes how much. As Zed Shaw once put it: ["If you want to measure something, then don't measure other shit"](http://web.archive.org/web/20140825165331/https://zedshaw.com/essays/programmer_stats.html).

But even if you fix that bug in your benchmark, generally speaking more specialized operations have more information available than general ones, so the more general operations can typically not be faster than the specialized ones.

In your specific example it may just be something very simple such as, you are using a Ruby implementation that is not very good at optimizing Ruby code (such as YARV, and unlike e.g. TruffleRuby) while at the same time have an optimized native implementation of `Array#map` and `Array#select` (again, take YARV as an example, which has C implementations for both of those, and is generally not capable of optimizing Ruby code very well).

And lastly, writing correct microbenchmarks is hard. Really, really, really hard. I encourage to read and understand this entire discussion thread on the [mechanical-sympathy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy) Mailing list: [JMH vs Caliper: reference thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/m4opvy4xq3U). While it is specifically about Java benchmarking (actually about *JVM* benchmarking), many of the arguments apply to *any* modern high-performance OO execution engine such as Rubinius, TruffleRuby, etc. and to a lesser extent also to YARV. Note that most of the discussion is about writing microbenchmark *harnesses*, not writing microbenchmarks per se, i.e. it is about writing frameworks that allow developers to write correct microbenchmarks *without* having to know about that stuff, but unfortunately, even with the best microbenchmark harnesses (and Ruby's `Benchmark` is actually not a very good one), you still need to have a very deep understanding of modern compilers, garbage collectors, execution engines, CPUs, hardware architectures, but also statistics.

Here is a good example of a failed benchmark that may not be obvious to the untrained benchmark writer: [Why is printing “B” dramatically slower than printing “#”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21947627/2988).

Answer (score 1):

While analyzing any algorithms, we mostly consider time complexity and space complexity. Before analyzing different algorithms to solve a specific task, the first and foremost thing is to design different algorithms that perform the same task and returns the same desired output.

Let's write a program that performs the same task *(iterating through the array 100 times. That's it nothing else.)* without storing any result *(because I am not sure what kind of output you want)*

Here is the code snippet for **bench.rb** file

```
require 'benchmark'
array = (1..100000).to_a
puts Benchmark.measure {
  100.times do
    array.map { |el| el.even? }
  end
}

puts Benchmark.measure {
  100.times do
    array.each { |el| el.even? }
  end
}

puts Benchmark.measure {
  100.times do
    array.select { |el| el.even? }
  end
}
```

I have run this code 3 times and the results are as follows:

```
Output: 

Attempt 1:
0.548562   0.021844   0.570406 (  0.571088)
0.457079   0.000345   0.457424 (  0.457774)
0.516487   0.010758   0.527245 (  0.527843)

Attempt 2:
0.544863   0.021756   0.566619 (  0.568487)
0.458062   0.000514   0.458576 (  0.459249)
0.508665   0.010847   0.519512 (  0.520401)

Attempt 3:
0.583084   0.022554   0.605638 (  0.606023)
0.509447   0.000665   0.510112 (  0.511088)
0.548483   0.012212   0.560695 (  0.561534)
```

I can see `Array#each` as the clear winner based on the written example. The output may vary based on your requirement but the ground rule should be the same that the algorithms should return the same desired output.

Comment: *"Let's write a program that performs the same task"* Every piece of code given performs a different task in your examples. `array.map { |el| el.even? }` will check if the number is even and output a new array (of size 100,000) with `true` and `false` values. `array.each { |el| el.even? }` will check if the number is even and nothing more. `array.select { |el| el.even? }` will check is the number is even and output a new array (of size 50,000) with only even numbers. Those are not remotely the same tasks.

Comment: Yes. That's correct and it defines the difference between `each`, `map` and `select`. Internally they work different and that's why their time complexity will also vary. 
I was just trying to execute the loop with the same logic( `el.even?` ) and not storing results anywhere or executing any further logic based on the output. 
Based on the requirement these methods come into the picture.

Answer (score 0):

well in the second case of both examples, there's an assignment during each iteration. The first one isn't assigning anything.

Comment: This is a very low effort answer. See the other answer for an example of a good answer.