Why is git log significantly slower when outputting to a tty?
In a large monorepo (.git directory 10GB), I have observed the following behavior.
# When outputing to a file, it is very fast:
time git  log   -2  > /tmp/X

real    0m0.076s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.046s

# When outputting to the tty, it is more than 10x slower:
time git  log   -2
# ... Output omitted

real    0m0.830s
user    0m0.078s
sys     0m0.586s

Here are all of my log-related configs:
$ git config -l | grep log

log.mailmap=true
core.logallrefupdates=true

What causes the difference in performance, and how can I get the same performance when git log is outputting to a tty?

More observations:

In a smaller repo, git log -2 is fast even when outputting to tty, so the problem seems correlated with a large repo.
real    0m0.057s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.022s


Cat on the output file is fast, so it is not just writing to stdout that is slow.
time cat /tmp/X
real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.005s


Forcing a tty with expect's unbuffer also slows down git log:
time unbuffer git  log   -2 > /tmp/X

real    0m1.007s
user    0m0.104s
sys     0m0.669s


By comparison, unbuffer itself has ~240 ms overhead:
time unbuffer cat /tmp/X

real    0m0.239s
user    0m0.033s
sys     0m0.111s




when output is redirected into file - it is basically copy into memory/file cache, but output to tty requires some additional line wrapping/ansi sequence detection logic to run on every symbol, check for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947452/why-is-printing-b-dramatically-slower-than-printing

also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857052/why-is-printing-to-stdout-so-slow-can-it-be-sped-up

Not sure why there's a close vote. This question is about git which is a software tool used primarily by programmers.

Try to run time git  log   -2  > output on a very slow disk or a network filesystem. ;-) I.e., your question is not about git, it's about writing to a file (OS, driver, disk) vs writing to a tty (OS, driver, physical terminal). Speed very much depends on the OS, drivers and hardware.

The fact that I get different speeds depending on the size of the repo suggests that it's not about disk but more about the behavior of git? See the additional observations.

Try git --no-pager log --no-color.

@Schwern Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, that shaves off maybe 4 ms at most; still seeing 0.796s on time git --no-pager log --no-color -2.

I can't reproduce your results on MacOS, tho I don't have a 10G monorepo to check on. We've eliminated your pager and color as differences. The high sys time is suspect. Try strace or your equivalent. What locale and character set are you using?

Try temporarily removing your personal git config and see if it persists. Check git config --list --show-origin to see if there's any odd configurations in the repository itself.

I'm actually running on MacOS, where strace does not really work. I'll try with ktrace and the other suggestions.

Removing personal gitconfig did not fix the issue.

on top of Schwern's suggestion (--no-pager --no-color) there are a few extra "smart switches" that git log turns on when detecting a TTY on stdout. One of them is: it adds the refs decoration on the commit logs, perhaps some other users will think of more differences. Check if git log -2 | cat (which also writes on the terminal) is as slow as git log -2.

also: how big is your .mailmap file ?

@LeGEC, It looks like time git log -2 | cat is as fast as writing time git log -2 > /dev/null! Thanks for the suggestion. .mailmap is < 1 KB.

ok, you may try to set the output format explicitly, for example: --pretty="%h %s" (<- similar to "--oneline", but no smartness with it) you may even try to let git choose the colors to check if it triggers a performance issue: --pretty="%C(auto)%h %s%C(reset)" (you may try other formatting strings, I used that one because it is pretty straightforward to remember and type :) )

to trace git: look at git help git, and search for GIT_TRACE (and following) environment variables.

@LeGEC, I posted an answer to summarize, but if you want to post an answer instead, I'll accept your answer and delete mine.

As written in your answer, I think you have identified the cause for your slowness: a very high number of references in your local repository slows down git log when it tries to print the decoration for each commit.

Check what kind of references make the bulk of these. You can compare the following numbers:
wc -l .git/packed-refs  # total refs

git branch | wc -l      # local branches
git branch -r | wc -l   # remote branches
git tag --list | wc -l  # tags

If you find out you have a huge amount of remote branches: try running git fetch --prune to get rid of remote refs (refs in refs/remotes/origin/*) that have been deleted upstream.

If the 3 numbers do not add up to the total amount of lines in packed-refs, check what other refs could bring the count higher.

you can manually check packed-refs: it is just a text file, one line per ref,
you can try a bit of script-foo on the output of git for-each-ref, for example:

git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" | cut -d/ -f1-2 | sort | uniq -c

cut -d/ -f1-2 says "use / as a field separator, only keep the first 2 fields", you can narrow on the highest numbers, and get more details by raising the second number in -f1-x
# example: if you find out you have refs looking like `refs/history/*`:
git for-each ref --format=... refs/history | ... | cut -d/ -f1-3


Based on @LeGEC's excellent suggestion and some further experimentation, it looks like the cause of difference is decoration.
Thus, we have the following results:
# Slow
time git log -2
real    0m0.838s
user    0m0.082s
sys     0m0.597s

time git log --format='%C(auto)commit %H%d%nAuthor: %an <%ae>%nDate:   %ad%n%n%w(0,4,4)%s%n%n%-b%-C()%n' -2
real    0m0.850s
user    0m0.086s
sys     0m0.607s


# Fast
time git log -2  --no-decorate
real    0m0.078s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.055s

time git log --format='%C(auto)commit %H%nAuthor: %an <%ae>%nDate:   %ad%n%n%w(0,4,4)%s%n%n%-b%-C()%n' -2
real    0m0.053s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.024s

time git log -2 | cat
real    0m0.068s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.049s


now as to why the slowness :) can you: 1. check your current content of file .git/packed-refs, and number of loose refs under .git/refs (ls -R .git/refs or tree .git/refs or ...) 2. run git pack-refs once 3. see if slowness persists ?

tree .git/refs | wc -l has 15618

After git pack-refs, the slowness gets worse. Goes to 1.5s.

ok, that's weird. I'm out of tricks for today.

Also ls -lh .git/packed-refs after that command is 945K.

Aha! git pack-refs --all makes the time go down to 200 ms.

15618 refs would explain it. Decoration has to go searching through all those refs to find which are associated with the commit ID. Before packing that meant reading 15618 files on disk. After packing it has to read and parse a 945K file; faster, but still extra work. 15618 refs is a lot. You may need to clean up old branches.

To confirm it is decoration, try git log --decorate -2 > /tmp/X and see if that's just as slow. Then, copy the repo, remove most of the refs, and see how it performs then.

Yup, that is indeed just as slow as going to tty.
Unfortunately, I've already packed the refs and I am not sure how to force unpack the refs, so I can't replicate the original speed.

@Schwern: I think the OP has already established that: he has issues with git log -2 (meaning: he ends up 20 some lines printed on the output ? everything would be slow if printing 20 lines added hundreds of ms) and toggling %d in the format string directly exhibits the slowness.

@merlin2011 I did an experiment by copying the Ruby repo, adding 10,000 branches, and then timing log decoration before and after packing. The results are similar to yours. I don't think the size of the repository matters, just the number of refs and whether they are packed.
